# how to undo the line draw using CGContextAddLineToPoint?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext

I'm developing one brush application for freehand drwing and i'm new in core Graphics framework.

right now my application is ready to drawing only using below code

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
{
    println("Enter in touchesBegan method");
    mouseSwiped = false;
    var touch : UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch;
    lastPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view);
}

 override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
{
    println("Enter in touchesMoved method");

    mouseSwiped = true;
    var touch : UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch;
    var currentPoint : CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

    self.tempDrawImage!.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height));

    println("lastPoint.X :\(lastPoint!.x) , lastPoint.Y :\(lastPoint!.y)")
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint!.x, lastPoint!.y);
    println("currentPoint.X :\(currentPoint.x) , currentPoint.Y :\(currentPoint.y)")
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red!, green!, blue!, 1.0)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush!);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    //contexts!.addObject(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());


    self.tempDrawImage!.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    tempDrawImage!.alpha = opacity!;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    println("dot");
    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

 override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
{
    println("Enter in touchesEnded method");

    if mouseSwiped == false
    {
        println("false");
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

        self.tempDrawImage!.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height));
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush!);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red!, green!, blue!, opacity!);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint!.x, lastPoint!.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint!.x, lastPoint!.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

        self.tempDrawImage!.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage!.frame.size);

    self.mainImage!.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height ), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1.0);

    self.tempDrawImage!.image.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: opacity!);

    self.mainImage!.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    self.tempDrawImage!.image = nil

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

but in some application i see that they give undo functionality in their application so i also want to give this facility that if use draw a 2 line and press undo button than lastly added line remove one by one from the image view

i searched about that but i can't understand and none of the answer is accepted so i'm confused so please help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your situation since you are only adding the lines this becomes very simple. All you need to do is create a mutable array which will contain all the points from the user input.

Now on every touches begin or whatever you will use in the end you will create a `NSValue` from the point you already got in your code and add this value to the array I mentioned previously. After you added the line all you need to do is call some "refresh" method or rather yet tell the view to redisplay by using `setNeedsDisplay` which will trigger the draw rect method to be called. Rest of the code will be moved from this method...

Now in the target from the undo button you will remove last 2 points from your array (I hope no problem here) and call refresh or redisplay (same as on touch event).

So either you move your drawing code to the "refresh" method or to the "draw rect" what you will need to do now is first clear the context background, then iterate through your array of points and draw each of the line.

Simple enough?

Comment: If the number of points you are drawing is odd then the last one is skipped. Also when pressing undo if the count is odd you might want to remove 3 points and if count is less then 2 you should disable the option to undo.

Comment: which two points i add to array and how to redraw i can't get through because I'm new and it's my first time on graphics so i'm not understand. Sorry!

Comment: You add one point per touch even which you named as currentPoint. Then when you draw you iterate like for(int i=0; i<allPoints.count-2; i+=2), then lastPoint = allPoints[i] and currentPoint = allPoints[i+1]. Rest of the code remains the same for drawing.

Comment: but how can i remove from imageView can't understand theory points

Comment: Hi man i apply your answer but this work very slowly because of redrawing using loop so please can you give any suggestion?

Comment: How much drawing do you have there?! Anyway I guess you could simply add a bit of logic to only redraw when undo is pressed, you must understand that when removing an element there is no other way but to redraw. Anyway, add 2 more muttable arrays, one for adding elements and another for removing. Add elements in those two arrays either when undo is pressed or when another line/point should be added. Then in draw rect ceheck those two arrays and only redraw if the one for removing is filled, otherwise simply draw the ones added as you did before. Also merge those array in the end.